# Linux SED replace 0A with 1A

Tags: sed, replace, command, newline

I am working with car radio. OS here is QNX, and command set is very limited:
[image]

I need to modify file in HEX. I've found sed command, which can do it, but as I've tried to use it, I've stuck.

I need to replace this byte order:
8A 00 00 **0A** B8 90 4B to ->
8A 00 00 **1A** B8 90 4B and I have no luck. I have found some codes on stackoverflow like `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' file` which removes 0A, so maybe possible to remove and append 1A. Are there any chances? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already very close. With GNU sed:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\x1A/g' file
```

or

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\x0a/\x1A/g' file
```